# Pass a foreign table in a "form_for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two model

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :personal
  before_create :generate_profile
end
```

and personal.rb

```
class Personal < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

and in my controller i have :

```
def createinfo
    @user = current_user
    @personal = @user.personal
end
```

I want to do a form for like that :

```
<%= form_for @personal do |f| %>
    Trigramme : <%= f.text_field :trigramme, :input_html => { :value => 'blabla' } %><br />
    Nom : <%= f.text_field :nom %><br />
    Prenom : <%= f.text_field :prenom %><br />
    Poste    : <%= f.text_field :poste %><br />
    Bio    : <%= f.text_area :bio %><br />
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But i have an error and I don't know how to resove that. I think the path `current_user.personal` is not accepted by `form_for` although it print the correct thing when I only put `current_user.personal.trigramme` in the code.

```
undefined method `personal_path' for #<#<Class:0x8e15a28>:0x8e15308>
```

do you know how can I do this form?

EDIT : My route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#cvpage'
  get 'home'        => 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'        => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'       => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact'     => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'cvpage'      => 'static_pages#cvpage'
  get 'createinfo'  => 'static_pages#createinfo'
end
```

EDIT 2 schema.rb :

```
create_table "personals", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "trigramme"
  t.string   "nom"
  t.string   "prenom"
  t.string   "poste"
  t.text     "bio"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

add_index "personals", ["user_id"], name: "index_personals_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end
```

Comment: Post your routes.rb file, and where are you calling `current_user.personal`?

Comment: I put current_user.personal.trigramme just for test in the view of the controller (static_pages). I edited with route.rb

Comment: you not have method post on your route

Comment: what method? how do you code it please?

Comment: Can you post your schema file?

Comment: Edited to add schema.rb file.

Comment: "I think the path current_user.personal is not accepted by form_for ", where are you calling `current_user.personal` in `form_for`?

Comment: First of all, forms typically do `POST`, not `GET`. Then, you should specify the action this form is to be sent to. Either by a route helper or a hash with an `:action` key.

Comment: In `@personal` at the begining (that my problem). `@personal` is defined in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEAHH! I solve my problem (take a lot of time)

I put in my `personal` controller this :

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @personal = @user.personal
  if @personal.update_attributes(personal_params)
    # if update is successful
  else
    # if update is unsuccessful
  end
  redirect_to home_path
end

def personal_params
  params.require(:personal).permit(:trigramme, :nom, :prenom, :poste, :bio)
end
```

And i put in my view this form :

```
<%= form_for(@personal, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

Trigramme : <%= f.text_field :trigramme %><br />
Nom : <%= f.text_field :nom %><br />
Prenom : <%= f.text_field :prenom %><br />
Poste    : <%= f.text_field :poste %><br />
Bio    : <%= f.text_area :bio %><br />
<%= f.submit %>
```

Thank you to all of you !!